# Help me find podcatcher for Windows with Creative Zen support

Tags: windows, software-rec, podcasts, mp3-player, podcatcher

I've switched from linux, I've been using Amarok for podcast download and synchronization with my Creative Zen.
Now I'm looking for podcatcher that will work in windows with my player. It should have at least this features:

- downloading all episodes since last sync
- upload to Creative Zen as music (not Zencast) with genre set to "podcast"

Ideal podcatcher will also be able to delete already listened podcasts from player without my intervention.

Comment: Does Amarok not work on Windows with your player?

Comment: I've installed KDE for Windows (version 4.2.2 since Amarok is not included in a 4.3.0 tree), but there was no "devices" tab in the Amarok interface (I think it's not implemented yet in windows port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to use ZENcast Organiser. I've changed setting so that uploadad episodes are not converted to Zencast - genre is set to "podcast" so I'm able to listen only to podcasts by genre.

There is no possibility to delete already listened episodes, but I can set a limit that only so much most recent episodes will remain on a device. It's not as good as I wish, but it's close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/).  Songbird has been reported to work with Creative Zen Mp3 players, and it can automatically subscribe to and download podcasts.  It may not have all the features you're looking for, but it's your best option.